# “prev. next.” text in Google search results meta description

Tags: seo, wordpress, meta-tags, yoast

Strange things happend when I check my website in Google search results. I'm using Wordpress and Yoast SEO plugin. Meta description of site was typed in Yoast SEO plugin so everything is fine but at the front of meta description, I see this text: "prev. next. " and didn't understand why? I checked my front page source and there's no text like this at it... I'm confused. Any ideas?

Comment: If you view the source on that page is it in the meta description tag?

Comment: No, it isn't. Btw, that text are not from Yoast SEO plugin meta description input, but from footer paragraph. Also, these prev. Next. Are showing just at desktop search, in mobile search I didn't see it!

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing the SERP myself. Google will typically use the meta description as their page description on a search result. One exception that comes to mind is when highlighting a search term from the page content when this is not in the meta description. It could also be that their search index for your site is old and has not been updated yet. You can check for this on the desktop version of the search result by selecting the little arrow at the end of the green site link and looking at the cached version of the page.

Comment: Totally agree with @tshimkus Additional I can add. Did you test the search in Google with **site:exmaple.com/page-url**? Do you see the same in front of the description? If you search specific query and Google sees your content more relevant then your meta description, Google will use that and sometimes it could include additional text around it. In your case, this can be ALT tags or another element from your pagination navigation above the text Google chosen text.